# Deceptively easy looking PDF conversion that is causing me fits

Tags: pdf, pdf-scraping, tabula

I have had tons of success using Tabula to convert PDFs to CSV files, but this particular one is causing me all kinds of issues.  The file can be found at [here](http://www.dhcs.ca.gov/dataandstats/reports/Documents/MMCD_Enrollment_Reports/MMCEnrollRptNov2015.pdf).

It seems the multiple row spans is causing Tabula headaches.  I would not expect Tabula to perfectly convert the file and I would expect that I would need to do some post-processing cleanup (usually a few sed commands), but I am not even getting close to creating a CSV file that is a starting point.  I have tried a spreadsheet, no-spreadsheet, guess, columns, and area with no success.  Does anyone have any other ideas about what to try?

Comment: I just looked into the PDF. It is properly tagged, so one theoretically be able to easily extract the table using a mere tag-aware text extracter. Which PDF library do you use?

Comment: I would like to leverage Tabula for a solution and not add some other PDF extraction method.